# Saving more than one record of equipment with date and time selected in MySQL using php yii 2 framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

How can I a save different record per equipment with the same date and time, if the qty input will be more than 1.

Ex. 2 qty input?

I am able to save single record with date and time using foreach... here is my example pseudocode.

```
$equipments = array([equipments];
$qty_input = array([qty]);

array_filter = array_combine ($equipments, $qty_input) => //this will result with the equipments with qty inputted

foreach(array_filter as result){

    //save all equipments with qty input together with date and time selected as separate records

}
```

Thanks for the correction and ideas